# mssql exporting stops in validating step

Tags: sql-server, validation, export

I am using microsoft sql server and i am trying to export my database but i get an error in the last step. Here is the full report:

```
Operation stopped...

- Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)

- Initializing Connections (Success)

- Setting SQL Command (Success)

- Setting Source Connection (Success)

- Setting Destination Connection (Success)

- Validating (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "BookId".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - BookTable" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

 Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

  Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

- Prepare for Execute (Stopped)

- Pre-execute (Stopped)

- Executing (Success)

- Copying to [dbo].[BookTable] (Stopped)

- Copying to [dbo].[ChartTable] (Stopped)

- Copying to [dbo].[UserTable] (Stopped)

- Post-execute (Stopped)
```

It seems like there is an error in Validating step.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Bookid is an `AutoIncrement` field and you are trying to populate data into that table from another source. You have to use `Enable Identity Insert` in your mapping to allow the Bookid to be updated.

Also, be sure that your seed is above the last value you inserted in the data exchange or you could run into errors down the road because you turned off safety checks when you overrode the `Identity Insert` behavior.